# calling functions written in jquery from angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to call jquery functions from inside my angular code. So lets sat i have 3 functions `funcX(data)`, `funcY()` and `funcZ()` that are wrapped in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
.....
})
```

Now `funcX(data)` takes a parameter `data` that i get from an angular service and `funcY` and `funcZ` do some DOM manipulation. The DOM manipulation that is done is quite involved and i dont want to port that code to angular. So can i call these functions from angular?

Comment: jQuery functions? I assume you mean JavaScript functions. `So can i call these functions from angular?` - have you tried it? If so, what happens? Does it produce errors?

Comment: it cannot find the function

Comment: Have you defined the functions inside `$(function() { })` (i.e. DOMReady event)?

Comment: no. these functions are in some js files that i have included

Comment: You need to provide more code.

Comment: If you are using angular to retrieve the data, you should really be using it for your functions as well. There is no need for jQuery to be loaded if angular is used, as it also loads jqLite for use with angular.element

Answer (score 2):

If your functions are written inside of `$(document).ready()` like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(  ) {
    function a () {
        console.log("fun a");
    }
})
```

then they are only visible within that block and not accessible outside of it. Assuming that your functions are actually using jQuery in any way, you could add them to the jQuery object either as a global jQuery function, or as a jQuery method.

- jQuery global functions are added to the `jQuery` object itself.
- jQuery methods are added to the `jQuery.fn` property.

Example for both cases:

```
$(document).ready(function(  ) {
    jQuery.a = function () {
        console.log("jquery global fun a");
        // do something with jQuery here
    }

    jQuery.fn.b = function () {
        console.log("jquery fun b");
        // do something with jQuery here
    }
})
```

Now you could use these 2 functions like so:

```
$.a(); // global functions are called from the jQuery object itself
$.('.some-class').b();  // jQuery methods are called on selectors
```

---

Alternatively, you could create a new object in `global object` to store all properties and functions for your application. It's especially useful if you are planning to store non-jQuery code in there as well and your functions are not intended to be published as jQuery plugins:

```
window.magicApp = {}

window.magicApp.fun_a = function(  ) {
    console.log('fun a');
}

// somewhere in your code
magicApp.fun_a(); // works!
```